# Canonical user id with EC2 instance role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

My canonical user ID was granted access to an S3 bucket.

I launched an EC2 instance with an instance role.

On the instance I can list the buckets contents but cannot download, it looks like it's going to start but then I get `[Errno 13] Permission denied:`

Does canonical ID not include EC2 instance roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A canonical ID identifies an **IAM User**.

When an IAM Role is associated with an EC2 instance, it creates temporary credentials using the Security Token Service (STS). The resulting credentials are therefore a different entity from the IAM User associated with your canonical ID.

If you need to use that ID, then you will need to provide those specific IAM credentials to your application running on the EC2 instance (instead of assigning an IAM Role). You can do this by running `aws configure` on the instance and entering the credentials.